# How to center unordered list?

Tags: html

[image]

link to my current code, for some reason it won't center. Please help.

all style stuff link:
[image]

Comment: Please, post your code in question - not as screenshots.

Comment: Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 about code as images.  You say "it wont center", what is **it** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```css
ul { display:table; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>    
  <ul>
      <li>1234</li>
      <li>123456789</li>
      <li>12345</li>
   </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```